# Wrong eigenvectors using LAPACK eig function to solve bessel function

Tags: python, julia, lapack

I'm wondering if someone can help me with my problem. I've been trying to solve Bessel equation using finite differences so i can translate the problem to a problem of finding eigenvalues and eigenvectors. I'm expecting that the eigenvalues obtained from the numerical computation match with the zeros of the Bessel equation of first kind and the eigenvectors when plotted to be at least similar to the theoretical plot of the Bessel function. The eigenvalues obtained for the Bessel equation of order 0, 1,2 and 3 seem to match pretty ok with the expected values (i've compared the results with the theoretical values for the first 5 eigenvalues each time). The eigenvectors of order 1,2 and 3 also look pretty similar to the Bessel function theoretical plot but for the order zero Bessel function the eigenvectors do not look like the Bessel function.
Here's the code for the zero order Bessel function of first kind:

```
    nr=500
    Nr=nr+2
    r=zeros(Float64,Nr)
    V=zeros(Float64,nr)
    A=zeros(Float64,nr,nr)
    for z=1:Nr
        r[z]=(z-1)/(Nr-1)
    end
    for z = 1:nr
        if z == 1 
            A[z,z]= (1/(r[z+1]*(r[z+1+1] - r[z-1+1])))*( ((r[z+1+1] +         r[z+1])/(r[z+1+1] - r[z+1])) )  
        end
        if z > 1
            A[z,z]= (1/(r[z+1]*(r[z+1+1] - r[z-1+1])))*( ((r[z+1] + r[z-1+1])/(r[z+1] - r[z-1+1])) + ((r[z+1+1] + r[z+1])/(r[z+1+1] - r[z+1])) )  
            A[z,z-1]=-(r[z+1]+r[z-1+1])/((r[z+1]-r[z-1+1])*sqrt(r[z+1]*r[z-1+1]*(r[z+1]-r[z-2+1])*(r[z+1+1]-r[z-1+1])))
            A[z-1,z]=A[z,z-1]
        end
    end
    deleteat!(r,1)
    deleteat!(r,Nr-1)
    W,V1=eigs(A,nev=5, which=:SM ,ritzvec=true)
    for z=1:5
        W[z]=sqrt(W[z])
    end
    plot(r,V1[:,1])
```

Here are the first five eigenvalues obtained from eigs

```
    2.40483
    5.52007
    8.65368
    11.7914 
    14.9305
```

Also here are the theoretical zeros for the zero order Bessel function

```
    2.40482555769577 
    5.52007811028631    
    8.65372791291101    
    11.7915344390142    
    14.9309177084877
```

Also here are the plot for the eigenvectors for order 0,1,2 and 3

[Eigenvectors for Bessel function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/za1Zx.png)

So... I hope someone can help me... Thanks!